# inserting variables into "b" bytes

Tags: python-3.x, base64, byte

This is my current code:

```
 encodedstring = base64.encodestring(b"admin:password")[:-1]
```

Now i want to use variables for the username & password, something like this?

```
  username = "admin"
  password = "password"
  user_pass = username + ":" + password

  user_pass = b"user_pass <<<<?
  encodedstring = base64.encodestring(user_pass)[:-1]
```

How can i do this?

Many Thanks

Comment: Doesn't `bytes(user_pass, 'ascii')` do it? Or `user_pass.encode('ascii')`? Pick any encoding you like.

Comment: yup, bytes(user_pass, 'ascii') do the same trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, like this?

```
username = b"admin"
password = b"password"
user_pass = username + b":" + password

encodedstring = base64.encodestring(user_pass)[:-1]
```

Or are you saying that username and password comes from someplace which gives you strings?

In that case encode them.

```
username = get_username().encode('UTF8')
password = get_password().encode('UTF8')
user_pass = username + b":" + password
```

Use UTF-8 so that non-ascii characters work as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
base64.b64encode((user + ':' + password).encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: this one also works: base64.b64encode((user + ':' + password).encode('utf-8')) , many thanks guys.